# Permutation of boy and girl names

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations

During your pregnancy, you decided on a list of 23 girls’ first names and 16 boys’ first names, as well as a list of 11 gender-neutral middle names. To your surprise, you had quintuplets, two boys and three girls. Now you must select a first and a middle name for each child from the lists. The names must all be different.

Solution: $P(16, 2) · P(23, 3) · P(11, 5)$

I'm confused on where the middle name is accounted for. For example, in $P(23, 3)$, I interpret it as picking 3 girl names out of 23 instead of 6 girl names (first + middle) for 3 girls. I'm also confused on $P(11,5)$. Does that mean that all of the five children must have a gender-neutral name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states that the list of middle names are all gender neutral.

- The 23 girls names are all first names, hence choosing the girl's first names is the P(23,3).
- The 16 boys names are all first names, as you stated, hence the P(16,2).
- Then the only middle names, as the question states are gender neutral. The 5 must be picked from these 11, hence P(11,5).

You multiply these permutations to get the answer.

It looks as though you may have misread the question.

Hope this helped!

Comment: The $P$ in this problem stands for permutations rather than probabilities.

Comment: Correct. Sorry if that confused anyone, but I decided to use the same notation as the author of the question.